# Removing all Filters in MS Access but Maintaining field of view

Tags: ms-access, filter

hopefully a simple question for someone to answer and yes, I did try to figure out the solution to this problem before posting here. 
I spend a large portion of my day filtering through MS Access to QC data coming in. Whenever I remove all filters, the window always shifts back to the left. Is there an option somewhere in settings were I can prevent this from happening. In these really wide datasets, it gets quite annoying to constantly have to scroll to the right.

Best,
Matt

Answer (score 0):

No worries people! I figured it out. If you have a column (any column) sorted then whenever you hit "unfiltered" the screen won't reset to the left! Happy days!